# 404 error only on WP custom post type posts on nginx

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, url-rewriting, custom-post-type

My WP on nginx with url rewrite works just fine. However, I get an 404 error on the CPT posts. I wish to have the same url structure on regular and CPT posts (www.domainname.com/static_name/post).

Why does it work with regular posts but not with CPT posts?

Do I have to manually add the rewrite rules for the CPT posts to the ngnix config? If yes, how exactly?

CPT registration:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );
  function create_posttype() {
    register_post_type( 'my_cpt',
      array(
        'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Name' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Name' )
       ),
      'public'         => true,
      'exclude_from_search' => false,
      'has_archive'    => true,
      'rewrite'        => array( 'slug' => 'static_name', 'with_front' => false ),
      'menu_position'  => 5,
      'taxonomies'     => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
      'supports'       => array('title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields')
    )
  );
}
```

nginx rewrite:

```
    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            #alias directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just as a possibility can you go to settings > permalinks and just click save - then try your custom post type again.

Comment: I already did that multiple times without any result.

Comment: @SimonPollard actually this is exactly the solution that solved my problem, thanks.